# Heroku Build Failing Bower Error

Tags: heroku, build, bower

Please Help me out I am new to everything regarding heroku and bower assume I understand very Little Here is the heroku log.

Everything with this was working until yesterday and all of a sudden minor changes won't deploy properly

```
bower moment#>= 2.6.0                           resolved git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.10.6
bower angular                                 resolution Unsuitable resolution declared for angular: 1.4.4
bower                                          ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_1c565364c27a4cdb7538ade6aae8f158//node-v0.12.4-linux-x64/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1c565364c27a4cdb7538ade6aae8f158/node-v0.12.4-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! fronted@1.0.0 postinstall: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install;`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fronted@1.0.0 postinstall script './node_modules/bower/bin/bower install;'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fronted package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install;
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fronted
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:


 !     Push rejected, failed to compile nginx-buildpack app
```

Here is the bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ac",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "spin": "~1.1.6",
    "angular-spinner": "~0.6.2",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.4.0",
    "angular-ui-select": "~0.12.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.2",
    "intl-tel-input": "~6.0.4",
    "international-phone-number": "~0.0.8",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.3",
    "angular-ui-notification": "~0.0.11",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.8.0",
    "angular-sweetalert": "~1.1.0"
  },

  "resolutions": {
  "angular": "~1.4.0"
},

  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "frontApp",
  "resolutions": {
    "intl-tel-input": "~6.0.4",
    "angular": "1.4.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after installing moment via bower

Adding resolutions to your bower.json seems to solve it.

Example
  //dependencies
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.0",
    "moment": "2.12.0"
  }